# Convert joomla articles to static html

Tags: html, joomla

As i am new to joomla, its been difficult to work in joomla. I need to convert joomla to static html website. Is there any extensions / modules / plugins available?

Please give me solution / suggestions on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965436/joomla-to-static-html-website

Comment: `wget -r` should do the trick.

Comment: Just go to File > Save page as. Thats it. This will convert any open-source to static HTML.

For multiple Documents, use HTTrack.

Comment: will u pls explain, what does it (wget -r) mean?

Comment: `wget` is a command line tool for *nix systems that retrieves a webpage. The `-r` flag makes it go recursive, so include all linked pages and images as well.

Answer (score 10):

Try have a look at the tool 'Static Content' by Julio Pontes that let you export a HTML version of your joomla site.

Find it at github here:
https://github.com/juliopontes/staticcontent